# Android изменить текст в TextView на секунду

Tags: java, android

Есть такой код

```
textView.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.string1));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                textView.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.string2));
```

`runOnUithread` не работает, `textView.post()` тоже (весь интерфейс почему то замораживается на секунду). Каким образом можно изменить текст на секунду?

**Обновлено. Работающий код**

```
private class ConnectionErrorNotificator extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    TextView textView;
    String begin;
    String end;

    public ConnectionErrorNotificator(TextView textView, String begin, String end) {
        this.textView = textView;
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        textView.setText(begin);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        textView.setText(end);
    }
}
```

**Вызов**

```
ConnectionErrorNotificator cen = new ConnectionErrorNotificator(textView, string1, string2);
cen.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основной поток нельзя останавливать. Остановка основного потока равносильна зависанию приложения.

Используйте таймер или создайте новый поток и там его уже останавливайте, но имейте в виду: В адроиде как и в swing к ui элементам можно обращаться только из создавшего их основного потока. Asynctask Вам в помощь.

И еще, при повороте экрана ui пересоздается, если к примеру таймер стартовал и в этот момент поменяли ориентацию то вылезет ошибка, потому что пытается поменять текст в несуществующем TextView.

Comment: Спасибо, с Asynctask всё работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    int time = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView helloText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        long delay = 0;
        long period = 1000;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                time++;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        helloText.setText(helloText.getText() + " " + time);
                    }
                });
            }
        },delay,period);
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне не нужно обновление по периоду, мне нужно просто по щелчку кнопки изменить текст textview на секунду, не замораживая интерфейс на это время

Comment: не использую период тогда?

Answer (score 0):

```
                final Handler handler = new Handler();                 
                final String text = oldText;

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textview = text;
                        handler.removeMessages(0);

                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                textview = newtext;
```